# Is the WCF REST Starter Kit dead in the water... now?

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, starter-kits

Looking at an older stackoverflow post (back in June 2009, [Is the WCF REST Starter Kit dead in the water?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006309/is-the-wcf-rest-starter-kit-dead-in-the-water)), a Microsoft employee said they were pretty close to releasing the next version of the Starter Kit.  That was a looong time ago and... they haven't released one.  So I'm asking again, Microsoft... is that kit dead in the water?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be part of .NET 4 / WCF 4 that should be released next time (April 12).

I haven't heard anything whether some or all of the improvement in WCF REST will be back-ported to run under .NET 3.5 - probably not.