# Should I use POST or DELETE verb in jQuery.ajax() function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

This is from jQuery API docs:

> typeString 
>   Default: 'GET'
>   The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.

I am going to make AJAX delete links with jQuery. What I would like to know is specifics about browser support for DELETE and PUT. Which browsers support it? Is it safer that I just go with POST?

Given that I work in ASP.NET MVC I can decorate my controller actions with both DELETE and POST so both can be accepted.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go with POST.  You don't have to worry about browser support and future maintainers of your code will understand whats going on just fine.

Comment: Not just browser support, but also server support.  DELETE isn't commonly seen outside of WebDAV ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webdav )

Answer (score 1):

You could go with POST then set a form field named X-HTTP-Method-Override to DELETE.

See SO question #467535 for specific examples:

[Is it possible to implement X-HTTP-Method-Override in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467535/is-it-possible-to-implement-x-http-method-override-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: That answer is out of date. This is built into MVC 2.

Answer (score 0):

Extract from form value and send request, call Html.HttpMethodOverride(HttpVerbs.Delete) in form.

Answer (score -3):

If all you're doing is deleting an item with a certain ID, GET should suit your purposes: http://www.diffen.com/difference/Get_vs_Post

Just make sure you handle a case where someone tries to delete something that's already deleted

Comment: GET is a **bad** thing to do when your URLs manipulate some persistent store like a DB. What if a search engine followed it?

Comment: No way for GET. Security risks.